# How do i get job name or step name in ItemWriteListener implemented class

Tags: java, spring-batch

This is my implementation and i want to print job name or step name as well with error message.
How can I do this?

```
public class WriterListener implements ItemWriteListener {

    private static final PlatformLogger logger = PlatformLogger.getLogger(WriterListener.class);

    @Override
    public void beforeWrite(List list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterWrite(List list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception e, List list) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while writing {}", Arrays.toString(list.toArray()), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a step scoped listener and in inject the job/step name in it. Here is a quick example:

```
public class WriterListener implements ItemWriteListener {


    private static final PlatformLogger logger = PlatformLogger.getLogger(WriterListener.class);

    private String stepName;

    public WriterListener(String stepName) {
        stepName = stepName;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeWrite(List list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterWrite(List list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception e, List list) {

        // use this.stepName in the log message here
        logger.error("Exception occurred while writing {}", Arrays.toString(list.toArray()), e);
    }
}
```

You can declare your listener as a scoped bean as follows:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public WriterListener writerListener(@Value("#{stepExecution.stepName}") String stepName) {
    return new WriterListener(stepName);
}
```

Once this is done, you can register the listener in your step as follows:

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
    return jobs.get("job")
            .start(steps.get("step")
                    .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                    .reader(itemReader())
                    .processor(itemProcessor())
                    .writer(itemWriter())
                    .listener(writerListener(null))
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: In this way, can I get JobId and StepId on the itemWriter()?
I need to validate the data on the itemWriter() and if the validation fails I need to put an error log that needs to be required JobId and StepId.

Comment: @AnjanBiswas You can apply the same idea to the item writer by making it step-scoped as well.

Comment: I do not implement ItemWriteListener. I just @StepScope on ItemWriter and use "#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"
like: public ItemWriter<LeadInfo> leadInfoWriter(@Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}") ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext)   --- but getting "stepExecutionContext" value is null.
what mistake here? could you please explain?

Comment: implements StepExecutionListener solve my problem. Thank you all

Comment: I save stepId and jobId to global variables with overwriding beforeStep. But it will set to null after next itemProcessor. how can I save stepId and jobId with global variable?

Comment: @AnjanBiswas This seems like a different case. Please open a question and share your code and I will try to help.

Comment: solved using JobInstance. Also, try to ask questions for better solutions.